# Errors while installing kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, kivy

Beginner pythoner here, I've been self-teaching myself programming for a few months, and would like to try app development with kivy, so tried to install it. I copy pasted all the commands into the cmd window, and every one of them seemed to work, there was no sign of anything wrog. However, at the last step, the installation, a big load of red errors came up that I don't know what to do with. Any ideas why it didn't work?

Ps. I've already tried to install it several times.
[screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZunKT.png)screenshot2][2][screenshot3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcITN.png)[screenshot4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwXUa.png)[screenshot5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ey2LM.png)[screenshot6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Pn8m.png)

Comment: which version of python do you have

Comment: If there are any errors, please include the important details as [formatted code blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) as that is [best practice](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/5586359).

Answer (score 0):

Use this for installation of kivy

pip install https://github.com/kivy/kivy/archive/master.zip